# reducing spaces in TOC titles

Tags: spacing, table-of-contents

Is it possible to manage that space in this following TOC defined in the picture between alphabets and related titles to make smaller, please ?
Knowing that the definition of these titles is `\renewcommand\theparagraph{\alph{paragraph}}`.

[image]

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way paragraph entries are typeset in the ToC is controlled by `\l@paragraph`, which is defined as

```
\renewcommand*\l@paragraph{\@dottedtocline{4}{10em}{5em}}
```

The third argument for `\@dottedtocline` gives the distance between the entry number and the entry title, so you can reduce the default value (`5em`) to the desired new value. A complete example, using `2em`:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{longtable}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}
\renewcommand\theparagraph{\alph{paragraph}}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\l@paragraph{\@dottedtocline{4}{10em}{2em}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Test}
\section{Test}
\subsection{Test}
\subsubsection{Test}

\paragraph{Raffinement du cas d'utilisation \og Mettre-\`a-jour postes de travail \fg}
\paragraph{Raffinement du cas d'utilisation \og Consulter statistiques \fg}
\paragraph{Raffinement du cas d'utilisation \og Rechercher \fg}
\paragraph{Raffinement du cas d'utilisation \og Gérer arborescence NTFS des 0applications métiers \fg}
\paragraph{Raffinement du cas d'utilisation \og Gérer dossiers spécifiques \`a administrer \fg}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The same can be obtained with the help of the `tocloft` package.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}
\renewcommand\theparagraph{\alph{paragraph}}

\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\cftparanumwidth}{2em}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Test}
\section{Test}
\subsection{Test}
\subsubsection{Test}

\paragraph{Raffinement du cas d'utilisation \og Mettre-\`a-jour postes de travail \fg}
\paragraph{Raffinement du cas d'utilisation \og Consulter statistiques \fg}
\paragraph{Raffinement du cas d'utilisation \og Rechercher \fg}
\paragraph{Raffinement du cas d'utilisation \og Gérer arborescence NTFS des 0applications métiers \fg}
\paragraph{Raffinement du cas d'utilisation \og Gérer dossiers spécifiques \`a administrer \fg}

\end{document}
```

Output

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Another approach by »[titletoc](http://ctan.org/pkg/titletoc)«.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{selinput}  % Replacement for »inputenc«
\SelectInputMappings{  % Semi-automatic detection
  agrave={à},          % of input encoding by
  eacute={é}           % a list of selected glyphs
}                      % see: http://partners.adobe.com/public/developer/en/opentype/glyphlist.txt
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{titletoc}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}
\renewcommand\theparagraph{\alph{paragraph}}

\dottedcontents{paragraph}[12.6em]{}{1.5em}{1pc}

\begin{document}
  \tableofcontents

  \chapter{Test}
    \section{Test}
      \subsection{Test}
        \subsubsection{Test}
          \paragraph{Raffinement du cas d'utilisation \og Mettre-\`a-jour postes de travail \fg}
          \paragraph{Raffinement du cas d'utilisation \og Consulter statistiques \fg}
          \paragraph{Raffinement du cas d'utilisation \og Rechercher \fg}
          \paragraph{Raffinement du cas d'utilisation \og Gérer arborescence NTFS des 0applications métiers \fg}
          \paragraph{Raffinement du cas d'utilisation \og Gérer dossiers spécifiques \`a administrer \fg}
\end{document}
```

---

[image]

Comment: Wonderful !!!!!